# how to run a video file when an excel cell reaches a certain value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file where I enter my stats. for motivation purposes I want it to play like an achievement video when a certain cell reaches a certain value. like if I stuck to a diet for 30 days to get like a well done! 30 days diet! you are now a diet apprentice! 
don't really know how to do this code wise. tried:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("dietdays")) Is Nothing Then

Call diet1


End If

End Sub


Sub diet1()

If e2 = 30 Then

Call Shell("e:\1\1.au3")

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Any errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say e2 = 30, are you referring to a cell in the active sheet? If so you should re-write your code something like below:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("dietdays")) Is Nothing Then
        Call diet1
    End If
End Sub

Sub diet1()
Dim Shex As Object:Set Shex = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").value = 30 then
    'consider qualifying the Sheet as above instead of using ActiveSheet
    If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Value = 30 Then
        FName = "E:\1\1.au3"
        Shex.Open (FName)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: wise and true! truly wise!!